# get row count before pagination in neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, datatables, cypher

I have a little problem with displaying the results from neo4j. I'm using a server side jquery datatable, in which I need to define the iTotalDisplayRecords, which is the number of records that resulted after the filtering. My cypher query is like this:

```
UNWIND {json} as data
WITH data
WHERE (data.entry =~ {searchText} OR ....)
RETURN { entry: data.entry, name: data.name, .... }
ORDER BY {field} ASC SKIP {offset} LIMIT {number}
```

So, I need the number of records before the LIMIT is applied, but I can't manage to retrieve that number, anyone can help me with this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive idea: you can add a `WITH` doing `count(*)` as aggregation and collecting data into a collection that gets `UNWIND`ed later on:

```
UNWIND {json} as data
WITH data
WHERE (data.entry =~ {searchText} OR ....)
WITH count(*) as count, collect(data) as dataColl
UNWIND dataColl as d
RETURN { entry: d.entry, name: d.name, .... , count: count}
ORDER BY {field} ASC SKIP {offset} LIMIT {number}
```

Comment: That solution works but the performance is really slow :/ I'm already having trouble in performance loading the json with the first UNWIND. Thank you for your answer

Comment: you're question initially wasn't about performance ;-)
Maybe using two statements, one for counting the other for getting paginated results might help. If your `{json}` is huge, mabye some preprocessing on client's side can help.

Comment: I think I'm just gonna store each record as a key in Redis database, do the filtering in there and then load the result as a json in neo4j and do the ORDER and LIMIT, what do you think? P.S: I can't do preprocessing on client's side, the json is about 27 000 records